# UISegmented Control does not appear in right style

Tags: ios

I've init a UISegmentedControl in iOS 8, but for some reason it appears with a gray background like in the older style (code below).

The view is loaded programmatically, not from XIB. If added to an XIB file, it appears normally.

It looks like this:

[image]

But should look like this:

[image]

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"Info", @"Medical", @"Team", @"Notes"]];
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(contentLeftMargin, segmented_control_y, content_width, segmented_control_height);
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Comment: Are you programmatically altering its `UIAppearance`?  If so, it would appear normally in IB, but different at runtime.

Comment: No. I am not altering the UIAppearance.

Comment: Is this code is the only code about your UISegmentedControl?

Comment: I wasn't personally, but the previous developer set some defaults. Thanks, @PetahChristian I found the code. What can be said about users down-voting my post I don't know. No feedback on how I asked improperly.

Answer (score 0):

The previous developer set app-wide defaults in applicationDidFinishLoadingWithOptions.

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"segmented_bg_selected"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```